# How set locale in smooks

Tags: java, kotlin, smooks

is there a way to set locale en-US in smooks?
I have a problem with decimal numbers when I launch the application in my local becouse:

```
Locale.getDefault().toLanguageTag() == "it-IT"
```

so I would like that smooks always take locale like en-US

Comment: add `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);` before creating `Smooks` object.

Comment: ok, but is there a way for change it only for smooks ?